# How can I configure Redis as a Spring Cloud Dataflow Source?

Tags: redis, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've search for examples and I have not found any.

My intention is to use a Redis Stream as a source to Spring Cloud Dataflow and route messages to AWS Kinesis or S3 data sinks

Redis is not listed as a Spring Cloud Dataflow source. Will I have to create a custom binder?

Redis only seems available as a sink with PubSub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be a redis-binder for Spring Cloud Stream, but that has been deprecated for a while now. We have plans to implement a binder for Redis Streams in the future, though.

That said, if you have data in Redis, it'd be good to start building a `redis-source` as a custom application. We have many [suppliers/sources](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/master/functions/supplier) that you can use as a reference.

There's currently also a [blog-series](https://spring.io/blog/2020/09/29/case-study-remote-file-ingest-with-spring-cloud-data-flow) in the works, which can be of further guidance when building custom applications.

Lastly, feel free to contribute the `redis-supplier/source` to the applications repo, we can collaborate on a pull request.